# If I want to send just text string(secure data) from android phone to android wear(watch), what should I do for that?

Tags: android, security, wear-os

If I want to send just text string(secure data) from android phone to android wear(watch), what should I do for that (how to write code or what kind of api to use )?

The text string should be safe from malicious apps on android phone..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send String messages (or simple data as integers, floats, ...), you should use te sendMessage method from the Message API. 
You can find the documentation here : https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html 
And you can follow this quick tutorial from Google : https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html

As for the secure part, I don't think there is a method for that in the API, you might have to write a protocol yourself.